# How to set .NET's DateTime value to XML's date field with BizTalk mapping?

Tags: c#, datetime, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have a [Script functoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOtxl.png) into my BizTalk mapping, which uses C# and creates DateTime value, which I want to set to "date" field of result schema. This field has type "xs:date"

Functoid's code:

```
public DateTime GetValue()
{
    string[] dateArray = "2017-06-19".Split('-');
    DateTime result = new DateTime(int.Parse(dateArray[0]), int.Parse(dateArray[1]), int.Parse(dateArray[2]));
    return result;
}
```

When I test a map, I get an error

> "The 'date' element is invalid - The value '2017-06-19T00:00:00' is
>   invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:date' - The string
>   '2017-06-19T00:00:00' is not a valid Date value."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: return a string: `result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` ? Although I don't understand why you have a valid string, map it to a DateTime and then wonder what to do with th added time...

Comment: At first I had tried to use directly initial string, but looks like I have missed something. Now it has worked correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your process is not correct.  But it's very easy to resolve.

You need to use [TryParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert from the string format to a valid DataTime instance.

Then, you use [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) with the "o" [Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) to emit a xs:date compatible string.